# Mutavault and effects

Tags: magic-the-gathering

when I have "Mentor of the Meek" and the "Mutavault"-land on the battlefield, and when I make Mutavault into a 2/2 creature, can I draw a card when I pay the mana cost for a creature entering the battlefield under my control?

Same question applies to "Suture Priest". Can I gain life using Suture Priest's and Mutavault's abilities?

Thanks friends!

Answer (score 3):

No. Permanents that are on the battlefield, but change their types, do not trigger enter-the-battlefield or leave-the-battlefield effects. The Mutavault is changed into a creature while it is on the battlefield, so it did not enter the battlefield as a creature and cannot trigger Mentor of the Meek or Suture Priest.

Wizards of the Coast has made this rule an explicit ruling for other lands that become creatures, e.g. [Celestial Colonnade](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=177545), but it applies identically to any permanent that is on the battlefield and then changes its type: In all such cases, it does not enter the battlefield and so no enter-the-battlefield triggers of any kind will fire.